# Forcing Managed Object to be dirty

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

Is there a way to force a managed object into the dirty state?  I have a managed object that has a relationship to a parent managed object.  If I change a property on the child managed object, I was curious if there is a way to put the parent managed object into a dirty state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- On Mac, you should use `NSPersistentDocument` for most cases where this would be useful.
- On iOS 5+, you should use `UIDocument`.

If these aren't possible, then you can either have the parent observe changes in its children, or have children set a changed flag on their parent. In either case, you can modify some "last changed" property to cause yourself to become dirty.

You can also create a method like `-hasChangedChildren` that would walk the children tree and return `YES` if any are dirty. This has the advantage of not actually modifying the object, so you don't impact any Core Data optimizations. The docs do not forbid modifying `hasChanges` to behave this way, but I would personally be careful doing so.

But if at all possible, you should use the document classes, since this is what they're for.

You may also be interested in [Core Data Questions--Relationships, UUIDs, and Dirty States](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/221102-core-data-questions-relationships-uuids-and-dirty-states.html).

Comment: How would one use NSPersistentDocument to set a managed object into the dirty state?

Comment: You collect the objects you wish to put together into a document. When you modify objects related to the document, the document becomes dirty. This is the appropriate pattern for most cases where your question applies. The other approaches I discuss are possible, but almost always if you want what you're asking for, you actually want a document-based app. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Documents/Concepts/RolesOfDocObjects.html